# Why was a comment criticising an answer removed?

Tags: discussion, comments

I commented on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302418/

The answer is a self-answer from a programmer upgrading from a development environment unaware of UAC to one that is. The programmer is used to running under Windows registry virtualization.

The self-answer which has been accepted proposes disabling virtualization on the entire system. Anybody who has any experience of this knows that it is a terrible idea.

I left a comment making that point in no uncertain terms. I don't want future readers getting the idea that this answer describes a sensible thing to do. That comment has been removed. Why?

I fear that we are becoming afraid of criticism for fear of upsetting users. If we suppress critical comments then we won't be able to maintain the high quality of the content on this site. One of the things that distinguishes SO from newsgroups is that SO stamps on poor advice given by people lacking in knowledge. Is that stamping on poor advice no longer acceptable behaviour?

Comment: When you say *"in no uncertain terms"*, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I can't remember the exact wording. I probably said it was a terrible idea or a crazy idea. I don't believe I was abusive but the criticism was clear and decisive. My guess is that it got flagged as rude and abusive. But I feel it was honest and direct b

Comment: *Honest and direct* so you weren't cuddling the OP? Shame on you ...

Comment: Surely the comment was flagged, pretty difficult to deal with for a moderator if the criticism is technical.  They weigh word usage and that has a *very* low threshold.  They tend to pick an action that minimizes the odds for further complaints, you being a hi-rep user that knows the ropes and is unlikely to complain in general put you at a distinct disadvantage.  Consider the alternative, DV the post, refresh page with F5, vote to delete.

Comment: Your exact comment was: *That is a crazy way to handle this. Disable virtual store? Why don't you get your environment to handle UAC. Only 10 years behind the times! Obviously you are coming from the back of the grid with Delphi 3 but that's no excuse to pretend that the last 10 years did not happen.* It's not immediately obvious that's a rather verbose way of saying "Why not adapt to handle UAC?" or similar... so I can see why it'd be removed in response to a flag...

Comment: +Ninja thanks. Can you explain the process behind the deletion?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it got flagged as not constructive - a mod reviewed it and decided to remove it. To be fair I would have done the same... I had to read it several times to identify what bit was the actual warning amid the noise (and that's from a PoV that's there's supposedly definitely one).

Comment: @Ninja I had to read the question multiple times, all the comments, the answer, and then the link to understand what was being said. Would the mod have seen anything other than my comment in isolation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unless there's any reason to investigate further and open the post up and try and puzzle things out (post has a lot of comment flags or post flags as well - which there wasn't in this case) then mods really only see flagged comments in isolation and if a comment doesn't look like it has any useful content it'll normally end up being removed.

Comment: @ninja Kind of a shame that such decisions are taken by people lacking the information required to take the decision well. I get that mods don't have much time. But I'd taken the time to understand. It would be easier if we could get back to closing and removing such questions as NARQ.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: glad to hear you have time to spend to understand the context for flagged comments! Given that I handled 450 comments yesterday (next to a few hundred other flags), I have about 1 minute per comment per day, if I spent a full 8 hours on them. Perhaps you could help?

Comment: @Martijn I thought by commenting having taken time to understand was helping. I do appreciate your position. My biggest gripe is that questions such as that don't get closed and removed.

Comment: That comment might have had an ulterior motive.  Ignoring, if volunteers need to spend 8 hours of their free time a day to work down a flag queue then there's a bigger problem.  Time to let SE organize another moderator election to lighten the load, won't happen unless mods speak up.

Comment: @HansPassant note that I didn't say I spend 8 hours on the flag queue. I don't. But if I spent one minute on every comment flag I handled yesterday it'd have taken 8 hours. I blast through most comment flags far faster than that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and there-in lies the problem - *"I blast through most comment flags far faster than that"*. Like Hans said if the workload is too much the mods need to speak up rather then "blasting through" not giving the flags the attention they deserve.

Comment: @Lankymart: again, comments are disposable and temporary. This flag got enough attention, I didn't 'accidentally' delete it.

Comment: Comments being disposable and temporary to this degree is extremely worrying when we're regularly encouraged to use comments to point out dangerous suggestions in answers. Conflicting advice as usual.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit at least we are giving conflicting advice consistently... now let that nightmare sink in.

Comment: @Braiam: Indeed! :D

Comment: @HansPassant totally off-topic but why did you specifically say to "DV the post, refresh page with F5, vote to delete." Is there a reason for the page refresh that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Only way I know to get the [delete] link to show up.  Only available to users with 20K rep btw.

Comment: @HansPassant got it, thought you were referring to vote to close

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The comment was deleted because it was flagged as non-constructive, and I agreed.

The comment, in full:

> That is a crazy way to handle this. Disable virtual store? Why don't you get your environment to handle UAC. Only 10 years behind the times! Obviously you are coming from the back of the grid with Delphi 3 but that's no excuse to pretend that the last 10 years did not happen.

I don't see much info in there that is so crucial to not delete.

Take into account we handle *hundreds* of comments per day, we certainly don't have time to tease out all the history and context for every single one that is flagged. Comments are ephemeral by nature, easily deleted.

Comment: If you can't see the information in there, you either didn't spend enough time reading it or you have a reading comprehension problem. The only superfluous bit ("noise") is the very first sentence. Consider this rephrasing: *"Disabling the virtual store is a crazy way to handle this. UAC has existed for a good 10 years; you need to get your environment to handle it. Obviously you are starting from behind with Delphi 3, but that's no excuse not to start modernizing your application."* Would you delete that? Do you see the information now?

Comment: I see your edit added the boilerplate excuse about how many flags you process and how little time you have. Hmm, sorry about that. If you don't have time to do a good job, then you shouldn't be doing it. Ask the community team to hold an election if the work load is too high. I'm getting rather tired of this excuse every time a decision is questioned on Meta. It works about as well as telling your boss, *"but programming is hard, difficulty by nature, mistakes are easily made."*

Comment: @CodyGray: so why not drop the 'crazy' and 'no excuse to pretend' and the 'behind the times' attitude from the comment *first*.

Comment: @CodyGray: the work load is just fine; stop getting so attached to precious comments. Really, lecturing me about reading comprehension and work-load over a *dumb condescending comment*?

Comment: Emphasis. This *is* crazy, it *is* behind the times. There's no other way to characterize it, you can just tweak on the wording. I don't see how that is relevant. There is nothing offensive in there. David doesn't say the *person* is crazy, he says this is a crazy way to handle the problem. He doesn't say the person is a moron, he says that their application is behind the times. How would you characterize legacy code vulnerable to SQL injection? Same principle. What I'm unattached to is capricious decisions by moderators, poorly justified about time constraints.

Comment: @CodyGray: there are more constructive ways to word it. The flag was valid.

Comment: We active user also are very busy and handle huge amounts of content here. Sometimes we don't have the energy to write the perfect comment.

Comment: Sure, and I understand that too. I saw no reason to make a fuss over this; I deleted it and moved on. It was nowhere near anything we'd be concerned over.

Comment: Ok. I guess I don't really understand what meta is for then. I know that I don't agree with the lowering of standards here on SO. But if you don't want us to query why decisions happen then sure I can just not bother to ask here.

Comment: @David: I've had at least one accurate comment removed for being too negatively phrased.  IIRC, it had a WTF or "what the hell?" in it or something.  (My case was probably closer to criticism of the coder, not just the code, than your case).  Just learn to keep it technical, and say things like "you should not do this".  It's a small price to pay for having such a well-moderated site overall while still having it open to everyone, including people that are wrong or clueless about a lot of stuff.  It *is* a price, and I would have liked to see this particular comment stay, but it's worth it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: where did I criticise you for asking on Meta? I didn't mean to imply that you shouldn't have done this, asking why a moderator took action is a perfectly fine reason to post here.

Comment: That's what I took your previous comment to mean. That you didn't see a reason to make a fuss.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: sorry, but that's a rude comment, that consists mostly of  accusations: `That is a crazy way to handle this`, `Obviously you are coming from the back of the grid with Delphi 3 `. While you might be on the spot with those, the point of the message gets lost among all this noise, making the comment not that useful.

Comment: @Chistik No accusations. Just statements. I think disabling the virtual store would be crazy. Don't you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It may well be crazy, but it's hardly constructive to say (paraphrased) "you're behind the times, you don't know what you're doing, and your methods are useless". Instead of using inflammatory language like that, try phrasing your comments as *your* opinion: "I don't think that's a good way to handle this - I believe the method is a relic of the past - perhaps you should try doing X instead". That way, your comment is less unconstructive, and less likely to be deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray Until you've *been* an SO moderator, I suggest you don't criticise their explanations of why things are handled the way they are (i.e. quickly). There's more to effective moderation than just throwing more moderators at the job; that doesn't scale.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I wasn't really concerned about anybody's feelings. I was more concerned with making sure that future readers knew what a terrible idea this was. I was stating what I believed to be facts. It really is a crazy idea. I'm not from the school that says we should work extra hard to avoid hurting people's feelings. I think it's better to call out rubbish content for what it is. It was a truly spectacularly appalling idea. My opinion is that we need to be quite ruthless in removing and refuting such awful content. If the poster is upset by that, tough.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On the contrary. There's a [Be Nice policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) around here, which means you can't just say what you like. If people are upset by your manner or behaviour, that's *your* problem, not theirs.

Comment: @Art I know. I think that comment did not infringe. Criticism is not the same as rudeness.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That I agree with. But there's also a difference between criticising *constructively*, which is characterized by your opinions and suggestions to improve, and criticising *non-constructively*, which is what you did: "this is crazy, never do this", etc, with no suggestions, help, or improvements.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "*I think that comment did not infringe. Criticism is not the same as rudeness.*" True. And when you criticize *the person* rather than *the post*, you have crossed that line. Personally, I don't mind the "That is a crazy way to handle this." It's the "behind the times" and "coming from the back of the grid" that goes from being merely sharp criticism *of the idea* into being an attack *on the person*.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Handling UAC isn't a suggestion? My main motivation was to make it clear to future readers that they should think twice. Could I have phrased it better? Sure. I'm disappointed that we are judging content on how it looks rather than its technical merits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "*I'm disappointed that we are judging content on how it looks rather than its technical merits.*" That's the *whole point* of the "be nice" policy. You can call into question the technical merits of an idea all you want. But you can't do it by degenerating into personal attacks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That was a suggestion? I can't say I noticed. That feels like just another criticism to me, which is also part of why that comment wasn't constructive. And hey - we've always judged content on how it looks and is phrased - if someone insults you, you judge it and you flag it. If someone knows their stuff and writes an answer but the grammar and formatting are terrible, you judge it based on that and you edit it.

Comment: @nicol The comment removal was based on how it looked rather than what it said. I don't like that aspect of how the site has become.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "*The comment removal was based on how it looked rather than what it said.*" No, it was based on what you said. "*I don't like that aspect of how the site has become.*" I don't recall a time on this site when a comment making a direct personal attack like yours *would* have been acceptable.

Comment: @nicol Nope. That's not why it was removed. Nor was it remotely personal. Nobody was attacked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The person who removed it seems to agree with me. Why do you think it was removed?

Comment: @nicol Nope. That's not what Martijn said at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the comment didn't warrant any more action from a moderator than deletion, is what I meant. Do I think the amount of discussion generated over a comment deletion is a storm in a teacup? Yes, I do, but that's my opinion and doesn't invalidate that asking for a clarification is a valid use of Meta.

Comment: If you simply state that something is bad practice, even that is enough for people to see you as rude. When you then step beyond "just the facts" and deliberately choose aggressive terminology to strongly emphasize how bad the practice is, that is always seen as "piling on" or "unnecessary roughness" or whatever you want to call it. It IS rude, because our society says it's rude. Manners is how you get your message across. "That's crazy" is something you tell your friends after work, not how you communicate professionally. Skip the emotion, it doesn't have the effect you think.

Answer (score 109):

Let's break down your comment to see where things went wrong:

> That is a crazy way to handle this.

This is borderline. Personally I'm fine with it, since it's focused on the idea itself.

> Disable virtual store? Why don't you get your environment to handle UAC.

This sounds like useful information. I don't know much about Delphi, but this looks like something legitimate.

> Only 10 years behind the times! Obviously you are coming from the back of the grid with Delphi 3 but that's no excuse to pretend that the last 10 years did not happen.

This is where your comment *definitively* crosses a boundary.

You have moved from attacking the idea into attacking *the person* offering that idea. You cast aspersions on that person's knowledge and expertise.

Attacking a person is *always* inappropriate. It's perfectly reasonable grounds for deleting your comment. And there is absolutely *no excuse* for it.

This is not "becoming afraid of criticism for fear of upsetting users". This is not "suppress[ing] critical comments." We are removing *inappropriate behavior*, provided by a long-standing member who quite frankly really ought to know better.

> One of the things that distinguishes SO from newsgroups is that SO stamps on poor advice given by people lacking in knowledge. Is that stamping on poor advice no longer acceptable behaviour?

And there it is again, the needless personal attack: "given by people lacking in knowledge." Poor advice *is poor advice*, whether given by a newbie fresh off "Hello, World," or given by a 40 year veteran of the field.

If you cannot "stamp on poor advice" *without* "stamping" on the *person* giving that advice, then we can wait to do that "stamping" for someone who can behave themselves.

Comment: Yeah that's fair. That bit was off.

Comment: This is exactly, exactly it. One nit: *"...provided by a long-standing member who quite frankly really ought to know better..."* Probably best to leave that off, for the same reasons you cover for the comment. Similarly *"...for someone who can behave themselves."*

Comment: ... showing that it is tricky to avoid getting personal when the discussion becomes heated or if you get stuck in it for too long (like what happens if you write a prolonged answer) :P Better reread that answer or comment before hitting enter or [post].

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mod, I don't barely understand how SO works at all in fact, however in my limited time here I have learned a few things. It's a fairly strait forward issue. The poster of this question, is just wrong in what they are presenting, and thus they are drawing a wrong conclusion.

Its fairly common knowledge you can't use personal attacks on any SO site.

One can claim this wasn't a personal attack, but it was a personal attack. It didn't take more than .2 seconds to see it as a personal attack either.

> That is a crazy way to handle this.

This statement says you disapprove.

> Disable virtual store? Why don't you get your environment to handle
>   UAC. Only 10 years behind the times!

This statement is a personal attack. Reason enough to delete the comment. This is a personal attack on the person for being "behind times" and shows utter disrespect and discontent for anyone who would dare to be so far behind times.

Comment: Well, it wasn't meant to be a personal attack, and I didn't mean to show utter disrespect. At least not consciously. But the wording of my comment says otherwise. Sorry.

Comment: Why is this needed? Nicol's answer is far better and more accurate. The second part contained useful advice, it was the latter part of that you might deem a personal attack.

Comment: Your answer lays bare the very assumption that I'm unable to follow in other people's answers. And it might simply be that I'm too aloof to ever get it. I don't take offense easily to things that people say. But I just cannot understand in what way you or anyone else can interpret this comment as a personal attack. You have to seriously contort the English language to interpret "only 10 years behind the times" as implying that the *person* is 10 years behind the times. David clearly says "your environment" right before that. It's *the program* that's behind the times. Which is a provable fact.

Comment: @Lankymart Because I don't entirely agree with the other answer, so I made my own. SO is not about "there is only one right answer". I will explain my reasoning in my next comment to cody gray.

Comment: @CodyGray In an offline setting, reading sarcasm is a relatively easy task for most people. For example I can say "codygrey is an awesome person" which is a genuine compliment, or I can say "oh yeah, that codygrey is an awesome person" while rolling my eyes. Both statements say the same thing, one is an insult. The tone of the answer was not simply "giving advice" it was 'giving advice with a very strong undertone of "how dare you or your company be behind times"'.

Answer (score -10):

Now that [more information about the comment has surfaced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333829/1079354), we can see two problems: the information *might* have been useful, but the tone of it coming across was *not*.  Comments can and are often deleted for lesser reasons than this, but the very fact that the comment was deleted doesn't surprise me.

I still stand by my original opinion:  if you want to offer a longer-term solution to a problem, **you should write an answer for it.**  I don't disagree that this does introduce some form of burden to you in that now you have to drum up a solution to this problem, but given the alternative would be to have a terrible answer with a snide remark attached to it, most of us would want to see the better answer.

Of course...you did mention in comments:

> I can't write a post that answers the question because it's a poor question that should be closed.

If this is the case - I really can't say one way or another since I'm no expert on the technology being used here - then no amount of [constructive] comments could have redeemed it.  You should vote to close those sorts of questions and immediately back away from them.  I only offered the idea of you answering the question yourself since it seems like you have more insight into what someone in this scenario *should* be doing, and that kind of knowledge would be helpful to put into an answer.

Comment: Problem is that I am bound to write an answer to the question asked. I can't write a post that answers the question because it's a poor question that should be closed. And I'm also dubious about making an answer be a refutation of another answer as its primary goal. I did down vote it and vote to delete. Deletion would get the job done. Comments are the next best thing in my view.

Comment: Perhaps a good idea in theory, but correcting a misconception in someone else's answer should not obligate me to go through all the work of posting an answer of my own. That's precisely what comments are for. (Or edits, if the misconception doesn't render the entire answer unsalvageable.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Fair point.  However, the downvote sends the stronger message that this solution isn't ideal.  Don't see any votes for closure on the question, though.

Comment: @CodyGray:  That seems to be a common fallacy on comments.  They're not going to be around forever, so the correction or warning you leave for future viewers is not guaranteed to be around.  The only realistic way you can ensure that someone will see the warning of "hey, you really shouldn't do this - consider these approaches" is to answer the question.

Comment: @CodyGray No. Comments are not there to correct a misconception in someone else's answer. Comments are there to ask for clarification or to point out minor flaws. If *the entire answer* is wrong, and you have a better idea, post a new answer.

Comment: This is a Hobson's choice. In order to point out an error in someone else's answer, I have to sit down and compose a complete answer of my own? No thank you. I'll just allow misinformation to be spread. And what if the entire answer is wrong and I *don't* have a better idea, @Madara? I guess it's that same line of thinking that a question is not a duplicate if the duplicate hasn't been answered. I'm beginning to miss the days when the moderators and I were on the same page. I haven't changed.

Comment: @makoto It is not a "fallacy". There is nothing logically inconsistent about the position. In fact, the "fallacy" is the assumption that a comment is just going to disappear. They don't evaporate, and they don't expire. They have to be manually deleted by a moderator and/or in response to a flag. So assuming that my comment is not offensive and contains useful information, it is not going to get flagged nor should it be deleted by a moderator who is following the prescribed decision rule. So although your claim that other alternatives are more visible than comments is true, it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Makoto: "*However, the downvote sends the stronger message that this solution isn't ideal.*" No, it doesn't. Downvoting only sends the message that someone downvoted the answer. *Why* they downvoted it is not stated. And precisely *why* an idea is not good is vital information.

Comment: @CodyGray:  [I'm stunned that you don't believe that comments are not going to just disappear one day.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)  They may *not*, but the very fact that we can still post comments doesn't meant that they're not going to disappear one day for any ol' reason.  I mean, the fact that the Privileges section describes them as "temporary" should be enough to suggest this.

Comment: There is a lot of useful information in comments on SO.  Ideally it all *should* be in answers, but in reality it isn't.  It would be a big loss to SO if comments started to randomly disappear.  I'm pretty sure the "temporary" language used there is to make new users understand that it's normal for moderators to clean up big discussions in comments, or obsolete comments.  It doesn't imply anything about them disappearing by themselves.

Comment: Where does it say there that comments suddenly evaporate? I'm familiar with the purpose of comments; you don't have to patronize me. It describes them as a "temporary post-it note". I don't know about your office, but my post-it notes never just disappear on their own. They're there until I remove them, or someone else removes them for a very specific reason (like the task was completed and they've become obsolete). And like Peter says, I find that there is as much useful information in comments as there is in answers, so this theory you're holding is, if nothing else, impractical.