# How do you stop someone editing your question, even when it's protected?

Tags: discussion, edits

I asked a cryptography question on Stack Overflow: [Simple Java AES encrypt/decrypt example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example). I got an answer that fixed the problem. Many people upvoted both the question and the answer. As a result, the question got protected.

Someone came along who didn't like the accepted answer as the cryptography algorithm in the question has known flaws. They insisted the answer be removed. This sparked a lot of comments along the line of "the answer is wrong despite answering the OPs question". Note, the person in question has had most of their comments removed. In retaliation they decided to edit the question even though it was protected.

Is there any way of stopping this? Or should I just rollback any edits?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention

Comment: I feel like I know who this is though.... wasn't there a question about bad practices in crypto questions recently asked on meta?

Comment: When a question is protected, it means that you have to have at least 10 reputation to answer it. It has nothing to do with edits.

Comment: @Patrice I think you mean [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334000/sample-code-within-questions-about-cryptography-encryption).

Comment: @Patrice - yes there was, started by the person in question! I thanked them for pointing out the flaw and acknowledged it and explained I was just starting with a trivial example. They still saw fit to edit the question.

Comment: Just a [FYI] but SO has a [be nice policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).  The edit comment you made was not very nice.

Comment: @NathanOliver - true, but I cant help feel it was warranted as their edit was particularly nasty. Also, my comment isnt readily visible unless perusing the edit history.

Comment: Being nasty normally is never warranted.  If you have a problem with a users behavior then disengage, mod flag, and explain what is going on.  No need to fight fire with fire.  Also just because it is not in plain sight does not make it "better".

Comment: I wanted to flag their edit but couldnt see an option. I guess I just flag the question and report the edit?

Comment: I really don't see what's wrong with [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15554296/revisions). It's an improvement (albeit a small one) and it does not vandalise your post in any way.

Comment: Side note: if your question is so simple why would you even ask it? Obviously everyone should know the answer... Very unclear what value "simple java" adds to title of the post...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The example was simple, not the question. Why would everyone know the answer to a crypto question?

Comment: @TedTrippin there is no problem stated in the title - clearly such post either "asking for sample" or "code review". It is unfortunate that good post have such useless generic title... Reads like just pile of  words similar to many "simple debug java help" titles on -10 posts. Sometimes authors of posts just don't care.

Answer (score 11):

The [edit made by that user (revision 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15554296/revisions#spacer-8020684e-54b4-4c6e-af8f-8d55f9903592) was great. It added a more specific title, and it added an actual question to your question.

You should not want to roll back relevant edits when you simply don't agree on some other point with the editor.

So no, you can't prevent others from editing, and in this case, you shouldn't even want to.

That being said, and that's an [old discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158741/how-to-deal-with-highly-voted-answers-with-security-vulnerabilities), thanks to this question we now have even more copy-pasteable, actively harmful code on the site. You can bet this has been copy-pasted into systems that are now in production. I don't like that one bit, and I don't like the excuse *"But it's good to show how you shouldn't do things"* either, because that part isn't the part that copy-pasters will read.

Comment: [try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15554296/revisions#spacer-8020684e-54b4-4c6e-af8f-8d55f9903592).

Comment: @CodeCaster there's a link button just under the revision title

Comment: @Tensibai that link doesn't show the diff view ...

Comment: Aww, missed the diff view part, sorry

Comment: @CodeCaster the edit didnt _add_ an actual question, it just moved it from top to bottom. However, I do agree to some extent with your comment regarding "old discussion". However however, I did need an answer to my question and its the reason I started my question with "simple...". Companies that hire developers who just copy and paste such important things as security related code have only themselves to blame.

Comment: @TedTrippin alright I missed that despite the diff view, but my point stands: you shouldn't rollback an edit that improves a post just because you had a discussion with the editor earlier. :)

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to expect that there would be no bad code in *questions*. If the code was perfect, there would probably be no need to ask the question.

Comment: @Blackwood I don't see how that relates to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

[Protecting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) a question just means low-rep users cannot post an answer; this has nothing to do with edits (or being a high score question). The only way to stop (all) people from editing is to *lock* a question.

In this case, rollback the edit (as it probably conflicts with the intent of the original poster). If this ignites an ['edit war'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/295232), just flag for moderator attention. This might result in them locking the question to the intended state.

Comment: In most cases you don't have to notify a moderator about an "edit war", because they're automatically notified about that.

Comment: Yes, see [Put an end to rollback wars](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222644/310998) on MSE.

Comment: @Gothdo thanks - so it's triggered by rollbacks, not just edits. Interesting!

Comment: @Glorfindel content "lock"s are generally only used to prevent a situation where people can't agree on a state and keep wanting to flip between versions or vandalise posts etc... - mods do get auto flags though which we'll go in and have a look at and try to understand what's going on. A lock just keeps it stable until it's worked out what should happen.